# parent child relationship in analysis services 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssas

I have a table:
ID,
ParentID,
Code,
Caption1,
Caption2

ID - atribute usage = key; namecolumn = Caption1

ParentID - atribute usage = parent

Code - atribute usage = regular

Caption1 - atribute usage = regular

Caption2 - atribute usage = regular
When I browse the dimension parentid it shows in hierarhical way based on Caption1 witch is OK.

What should I do so when I browse by Caption2 to show also in hierarhical way. My business needs is to show in hierarhical ways when I browse by Caption1 or Caption2 or Code too. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own custom hierarchy